# Why my code is not returning the value of hypotenuse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, return-value

Basically, I need to calculate a hypotenuse of the right triangle
 First, my code defines if the triangle is right or not, and then based on the lengths of two sides it calculates a hypotenuse of that triangle but it is not returning my h value which I need to return as a task of this exercise. 
I can't understand what is a problem with returning h?
Why code is not returning it?

Thanks in advance

```
angle1 = input("what is a degree of the first angle? : ")
angle2 = input("what is a degree of the second angle? : ")
angle3 = input("what is a degree of the third angle? : ")

a1 = int(angle1)
a2 = int(angle2)
a3 = int(angle3)

length1 = input("what is a length of the first side? : ")
length2 = input("what is a length of the second side? : ")

l1 = int(length1)
l2 = int(length2)


def hypothenuse(a1, a2, a3, l1, l2):
    if a1 != 90 or a2 != 90 or a3 != 90:
        return ("\n sorry, but triangle sould be right -> one agle = 90 degrees")
    else:
        h = l1**2 + l2**2
        return ("The hypothenuse of this triangle is equal to:", h)

hypothenuse(a1, a2, a3, l1, l2)
```

Comment: It is. But you're not doing anything with it. Maybe you want to do `print(hypoteneuse(a1....))`?

Comment: Or `description, h = hypotenuse(...)` maybe, if you want those values later. But that would cause an error if there is no right angle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a value.  The problem is that you are not telling Python to display it.

You can display variables, strings, bytes, integers and many other data types with [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

This is what you are after using:

```
print(hypothenuse(a1, a2, a3, l1, l2))
```

As mentioned in the comments you can store it in variables.

I would highly recommend you add "error catching" to your program, in case a user inputs a letter and not something that can be turned into an integer with `int()`

For example if under `angle1` somebody entered `a` you would get:

```
>>> a1 = int(angle1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
>>>
```

A way to prevent this is to "catch" the error:

```
try:
    a1 = int(angle1)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an integer")
```

Don't worry if this is unfarmiliar right now, it will come up as you learn Python, and will become easy enough to understand.